# Rake tasks keep failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, mongoid

I'm trying to set up my development environment to work with an existing project that's using Mongoid. I've run bundle install and that worked fine, but I'm now trying to set up the database, and I'm running  `rake db:setup`

Here's the output:

```
[1] $ rake db:setup --trace                                                                                                                                                                     ✘
** Invoke db:setup (first_time)
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.+
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/cantango-36e3ce152717/lib/cantango/configuration/registry.rb:31:in `register'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/cantango-36e3ce152717/lib/cantango/configuration/candidate_registry.rb:10:in `register'
/home/chintanparikh/Documents/Work/project_name/config/initializers/cantango.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/cantango-36e3ce152717/lib/cantango.rb:23:in `configure'
/home/chintanparikh/Documents/Work/project_name/config/initializers/cantango.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:556:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `each'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/chintanparikh/Documents/Work/project_name/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:193:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `call'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `block in execute'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `each'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `execute'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `each'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `each'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:141:in `invoke_task'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `each'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block in top_level'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `run_with_threads'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `top_level'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:71:in `block in run'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:158:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:68:in `run'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.1/bin/rake:37:in `<top (required)>'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/chintanparikh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:create => environment
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? It looks like it's failing on the create step.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB is a schema-less database. You don't need to use any of the `rake db:{}` functions with it. The only thing you need to do to have mongodb up and running is to install it and then to start the server. You can find more information on installing MongoDB [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/)